# How to detect jQuery event (ex. click mouseout) on or off?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, jquery-on

For default

```
$().mouseout(function(){…})
```

The `mouseout` event is on in the page

Can I use any way to **detect the event is whether on**?

I want the detect method return a Boolean for me to use.

Hope to see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `$._data`, yea!

Yes, you can do so by checking this way:

```
console.log($._data( $(element)[0], "events" ));
```

#### Example

```
​$("#foo").on({
    click: function(){ alert("Hello") },
    mouseout: function(){ alert("World") }
});​​​
​$._data( $("#foo")[0], "events" );
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

#### In your code:

So, you can use the returning object and perform operations.

```
myEvents = ​$._data( $("#foo")[0], "events" );
// Check if the mouse event is set
if (myEvents.mouseout.length > 1)
    // Do something
```

Comment: Hello,thanks for ur help,i want to ask, in this case, $("#foo")[0] present click event,am i right?